# JavaScript: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm pretty new to JS and I'm trying to wrap my head around the object topic in JS.
What I'm trying to do is to set a property of an object prototype to an uninitialized array, so that I can later add multiple objects to that array (for instances of the prototype object)
My code looks like this so far:

```
function cocktail(){
this.prototype.ingredients = [];
this.printIngredients = function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i<this.ingredients.length; ++i) {
        console.log(this.ingredients.fluid);
        console.log(this.ingredients.amount);
        }
    }
}

var Mojito = new cocktail();
Mojito.ingredients.push({"fluid":"White Rum", "amount":0.05});
Mojito.printIngredients();
```

That throws:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'ingredients' of undefined

If I change my code into :

> this.ingredients = [];

it works but the printIngredients() method prints undefined twice. When I do:

```
var array = [];
array.push({"a":1, "b":2});
console.log(array[0].a, array[0].b)
```

everything works as I would expect it to. Can someone clarify what I'm doing wrong and where my thoughts got mixed up?

Comment: `this` doesn't have `prototype` property

Comment: `this.prototype.ingredients = [];` should be `this.ingredients = [];`. `this` refers to newly created `coctail` instance, that doesn't have prototype property.

Comment: `console.log(this.ingredients[i].fluid);` (notice the `i`). + what has been mentioned above.

Comment: What you're trying to do really won't involve the prototype at all. You need a list of ingredients that's distinct for each cocktail, not a list that globally records ingredients for *all* cocktails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to

```
function cocktail(){
this.ingredients = []; //this doesn't have prototype property
this.printIngredients = function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i<this.ingredients.length; ++i) {
        console.log(this.ingredients[i].fluid);//use the counter variable to get the fluid value at current counter value 
        console.log(this.ingredients[i].amount);//use the counter variable to get the amount value at current counter value 
        }
    }
}

var Mojito = new cocktail();
console.log(Mojito.ingredients)
Mojito.ingredients.push({"fluid":"White Rum", "amount":0.05});
Mojito.printIngredients();
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation.

Comment: @putvande sure, added the same inline.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are familiar with class-based languages, you could use modern JavaScript to avoid some of the confusion.

```
class Cocktail {
  constructor() { 
      this.ingredients = [] 
  }

  printIngredients() {
      // let is like var, but scoped to blocks instead of functions
      // for...of iterates on values instead of keys/indices
      for (let ingredient of this.ingredients) {
          console.log(ingredient.fluid)
      }
  }
}
```

This kind of JavaScript is available from:

- Chrome 49
- Edge 13
- Firefox 44
- Node.js 6

Documentation:

- [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)
- [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)
- [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0):

well, first you want to remove `printIngredients` method out of the `constructor` function, it will improve performance when it comes to a larger project since you don't have to create different copies every time you instantiate the constructor function, secondly, it is a convention to capitalize the first letter of your constructor. Last but not least, use `let` and `const` as they limit the scope to block rather than `var` that's function `scope`.

```
function Cocktail(){
this.ingredients = []; 
}

Cocktail.prototype.printIngredients = function() {
    // for in ... iterates on keys rather than values
    for (let i in this.ingredients) {
        console.log(this.ingredients[i].fluid);//use the counter variable to get the fluid value at current counter value 
        console.log(this.ingredients[i].amount);//use the counter variable to get the amount value at current counter value 
        }
    }

const Mojito = new Cocktail();
console.log(Mojito.ingredients)
Mojito.ingredients.push({"fluid":"White Rum", "amount":0.05});
Mojito.printIngredients();
```